# Shell script for change and replace using "sed"

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Trying to write test1.ksh which contains command to search "%s_sitename%" string and replace it with "%s_sitename%" and today date in file test.sql:

```
s1='%s_sitename%' s2=echo date "+%Y-%b-%e" s3=$s1$s2 sed -i 's/'"$s1"'/'"$s3"'/g' test.sql exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s2=echo date "+%Y-%b-%e"
```

is wrong. First you don't need echo, second you didn't enclose the command inside backticks (``)

```
s1='%s_sitename%'
s2='%s_sitename%'"$(date "+%Y-%b-%e")"
sed -i 's/'"$s1"'/'"$s2"'/g' test.sql
```

Should do it.

Comment: I used something like below: s1='%s_sitename%'
s2='%s_sitename% as of '"$(date "+%Y-%b-%e")"  which works first time correctly but when I use same second time file have value "%s_sitename% as of 2016-Jun-22" and it updated it like "%s_sitename% as of 2016-Jun-22 as of 2016-Jun-22"